# Has anyone had problems with the latest Super Image Denoiser (SID) add-on?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, .exr

The add-on installs and works fine for the most part. The Spatial mode works perfect and does wonders for denoising stills, but when I change to temporal denoising I'm running into issues. I'm noticing few things which are not available in any of the documentation of the add-on, and nor I have found any info on the web about the things I describe below.

1. When using Temporal Denoising under SID, the image is rendered progressively rather than normal square boxes.
2. Temporal Denoising doesn't use 100% of CPU and GPU. (Hovering around 35-40% in my case)
3. The animation renders fine in blender window and saves, however exported .exr are black and blank.

Basically I'm not being able to use the temporal denoiser for animation. Spatial mode is good for stills but useless for animations (Tried and had jittering on playback).

My PC Info:

CPU: Ryzen 9 3900X
GPU: RTX 3070
RAM: 32GB clocked at 3600MHz
Blender Version: 2.92

Edit: Contacted via his artstation email.

Comment: I think you would be better off contacting the SID author directly through gumroad or wherever you got the add-on from.  It's unlikely that we'll be able to help you here.

Comment: The profile on the gumroad doesn't have any contact, so left a comment on his YouTube channel. Hopefully he'll reply soon. Thanks @MartyFouts

Comment: @pritam raya the gumroad page has a contact, it's the "got questions, join the discord" line

Answer (score 2):

So get get a few things running.
You need to set a range for temporal to work, 7 is max, uses most memory, but has best quality.

Then you need to set a radius, this radius will make it blurrier but also cleaner, 25 is max, we usually used 18.

Then you need to make a few test renders, denoising with NLM denoiser and tweaking the settings for strength for example.

Then you will see how it will look like, after that you can denoise with these settings on temporal.

Now that's about the blockyness, let's talk about it being black.

It is not a normal exr file, but a multilayer exr file, Photoshop can't open it, after effects can't open it, no Adobe program can open it.

You can open it in blenders compositor, or Natron, a free node based video editing program.

It hovering at around that percentage is to be expected.
It doesn't use every core of your system, and only uses cpu to do so.

Additionally, temporal isn't good at denoising, I don't know what I said that made people think that. Probably bad phrasing in a video.
We initially thought it would be good, but turns out it's quite bad, so bad that it will be discontinued with blender 3.0.

Youre better off using sid super, It is much better at denoising and can handle volumetrics easily, while temporal can't.

I hope that clears up your questions :)

And if you want to contact me, you can simply message me on discord.
https://discord.gg/cnFdGQP

Kind regards, Kevin

Comment: Oh, I get it now. So, my assumption was it was using SID for denoising in temporal mode, turns out it uses NLM. I downloaded a plugin called exrio for photoshop and it's good now. I was wondering why did you intentionally made the add-on use only CPU? Also isn't is good to go all out on rendering, because on cycles we are doing pretty much jus that. Thanks Kevin for the clarification.